# Received memory warning crash arc uiimageview

Tags: ios, iphone, virtual-machine

According to vm emulator image IO_PNG_Data exeeds limit and cause crashes. i am using following code to load image view.I have researched a lot but nothing helps.

```
CALayer *imageLayer = self.img_user.layer;  
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:img_user.frame.size.width/2];
img_user.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getimgpath];
```

here getpath is the image at cashe, i have store the image get from url in cashe

```
NSString *stringURL = getpicurl;
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"userpic.png"];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    //obj_AppDelegate.img_path=filePath;
    setimgpath(filePath);
}
```

While loading uiimageview each time memory exeeds,and crashes pls help.

Comment: How large (in terms of both file size and pixel dimensions) is the image you are loading?

Comment: may i need to resize the image,its sometimes big,getting from webservice.why imageview not releasing memory using arc